# How to get the full menu?

Tags: 11.10, menu, gedit

I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 and when I run a simple app i.e. GEdit I now don't have the dropdown menu with i.e. "Save as.." Where is that menu now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you upgraded from, but in 11.10 application use the global menu. The global menu resides at the very top of the screen, and is hidden by default by the window title. If you mouse over the window title at the very top of the screen, you will see things like file, edit, view.

Comment: Thanks! I found it. They changed so much I could not follow.